# Implementing prototypes OR instantiating class objects

Tags: python, prototypal-inheritance, prototype

#### `updated 2010-06-15T09:45:00Z`:

- added an example for the "classes as instances" approach, and an explanation of the "instances as classes" approach; incorporated and referenced Alex Martelli's answer;

I'm wondering how to implement prototypal inheritance in Python.  There would seem to be two different approaches to this problem: classes as instances, and instances as classes.

The second method would seem to be more flexible, in that it could be applied to existing objects of varied types, while the first would likely be more convenient for typical use cases.

#### classes as instances

The idea here is to use a metaclass to cause instantiations to actually be classes, rather than objects.  This approach looks something like this:

```
class ClassAsInstance(type):
    """ ClassAsInstance(type)\n
        >>> c = ClassAsInstance()
        >>> c.prop = 6

        It's sort of annoying to have to make everything a class method.
        >>> c.jef = classmethod(lambda self: self.prop)
        >>> c.jef()
        6
        >>> cc = c()
        >>> cc.jef()
        6

        But it works.
        >>> c.prop = 10
        >>> cc.jef()
        10
        >>> c.jef = classmethod(lambda self: self.prop * 2)
        >>> cc.jef()
        20
    """
    def __new__(self):
        return type(self.__name__ + " descendant", (self, ), {})
```

I haven't really tested any complicated stuff with this approach, so it may have limitations.

#### instances as classes

With this approach, the idea is to use the `type` constructor to create classes from objects.  This is exemplified in [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042502/implementing-prototypes-or-instantiating-class-objects/3042540#3042540), although the example he uses for this approach implements copy prototyping rather than allowing the descendants to inherit later changes to their prototypes.

My approach was to do something like this:

```
def createDescendant(obj):
    return type(obj.__class__.__name__ + " descendant", (obj.__class__, ), obj.__dict__)()
```

which will work in sort of a javascript-y kind of way: changes to a given object will not influence its descendants, but changes to the parent object's `__class__` (like a javascript `prototype`) will.  I gather that this is because the `type` constructor **copies** `obj.__dict__` rather than referencing it in some sort of mro-ish scheme.

I attempted to implement an improved version that would allow true prototypal inheritance, wherein objects would inherit updates to the parent objects.  The idea was to assign the prototype object's `__dict__` property to the same property of the newly-created class, the one that becomes the class of the descendant object.

However, this didn't work out, as I discovered that the `__dict__` of a `type` cannot be assigned to; this limitation also applies to classes derived from `type`.  I'm still curious if it's possible to get around this problem by creating an object that "implements the type protocol", as is done with iterables, sequences, etc., but does not actually inherit from `type`.  This might create other problems, such as those inherent to the delegational approach that Alex mentions in the first part of his answer.

#### delegation

Alex also suggests a third approach, that of delegation, wherein the state of an object is propagated to descendant objects via the `__getattr__` magic method.  Again, see Alex's answer for an example, as well as details on the limitations of this approach.

Further insights on the practicality of these approaches, as well as alternative suggestions, are hereby requested.

Comment: @intuited.  Please remove your "update log".  Stack Overflow keeps a complete update log with character-by-character changes.  Also, please explain why you would ever want to do this.  It sounds like a complete waste of time.

Comment: @S.Lott: I wanted to make the update notice prominent because it was a major change; I guess it worked.  But with some adverse effects . . . that you could perhaps tell me more about?  What's problematic about putting an update notice at the top of the edit?

Comment: @intuited: "Stack Overflow keeps a complete update log with character-by-character changes"  What more can I say?  If you're making a "major change", then close the question and open a new one that's correct.  If you aren't going all the way to a new question, "Stack Overflow keeps a complete update log with character-by-character changes."

Comment: @S.Lott: Python provides rich class-oriented facilities with which to express complex concepts.  However, sometimes you just want to express that this object is like that object, but different in certain ways. This can often be most clearly and expressively done by copying the first object, and then modifying it dynamically. That is what I did with this post, and it's what I'd like to learn to do when programming in Python, so as to be able to use the paradigm most suited to such tasks. My update log could perhaps be considered a docstring that summarizes the changes in a prominent location.

Comment: Also, for a more in-depth (some would say long-winded) exploration of the virtues of prototype-based modeling, this post/essay by Steve Yegge is an interesting read: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html

Comment: "sometimes you just want to express that this object is like that object, but different in certain ways"  Isn't that what inheritance is for?

Comment: @S.Lott: Yes, but in the typical usage of the term, it applies to *classes*, aka *types*, rather than *objects*. Depending on the language, there's not always a clear line between the two; in Python it is blurry (since types are actually objects of the type `type`) and I'm trying to see where it really lies, and how traversable it is. This becomes particularly relevant when you want to alter a representation, an instantiation, of a given concept at runtime, and then derive further representations from it, based on the runtime changes, and then do the same to the derived objects, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you need future alterations of the prototype object to be transparently reflected in all "descendants", then you must have recourse to explicit delegation.  On normal methods, that's easily done via `__getattr__`, e.g., deriving from:

```
class FromPrototype(object):
  def __init__(self, proto):
    self._proto = proto
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._proto, name)
```

...as long as you're also inheriting the **state** of the prototype, not just the **behavior**. Unfortunately, non-overridden methods from the prototype will not perceive any state that may have been overridden in the current object.  In addition, *special* methods (ones with magic names starting and ending in double underscore), which are looked up in the class rather than the instance, cannot be simply delegated this way.  So, to fix these issues may require a lot of work.

If you're not concerned with "seamlessly inheriting" future alterations to the prototype, but are fine with taking a snapshot of the latter at "prototype inheritance" time, it's simpler:

```
import copy

def proto_inherit(proto):
  obj = copy.deepcopy(proto)
  obj.__class__ = type(obj.__class__.__name__, (obj.__class__,), {})
  return obj
```

each object built this way has its own class so you can set special methods on the class (after getting the object from `proto_inherit`) without affecting any other object (for normal methods, you can set them either on the class or on the instance, though always using the class would be more regular and consistent).

Comment: Interesting.  I worked your answer into a new version of the question, and also added some further explanation of my original take on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more robust version of the delegation approach.
The main improvements are

1. when the inherited member is a method, then a method with the same underlying function, but bound to the original calling object is returned.
   This addresse the problem that @AlexMartelli raises in his answer:

   > ...as long as you're also inheriting the state of the prototype, not
   >   just the behavior. Unfortunately, non-overridden methods from the
   >   prototype will not perceive any state that may have been overridden in
   >   the current object.
2. Cooperative inheritance conventions are followed so as not to break class based inheritance

One restriction is that the `Proto` class must come first in the method resolution order for initialization to work correctly

#### delegate.py

```
import types
import inspect

class Proto(object):
  def __new__(self, proto, *args, **kw):
    return super(Proto, self).__new__(self, *args, **kw)
  def __init__(self, proto, *args, **kw):
    self.proto = proto
    super(Proto, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
      attr = getattr(self.proto, name)
      if (inspect.ismethod(attr) and attr.__self__ != None):
        attr = types.MethodType(attr.__func__, self)
      return attr
    except AttributeError:
      return super(Proto, self).__getattr__(name)
```

#### delegate-demo.py

The call to `b.getY()` below illustrates Alex's point and would fail if the `FromPrototype` class in his answer was used instead of `Proto`

```
from delegate import Proto

class A(Proto):
  x = "This is X"
  def getY(self):
    return self._y

class B(Proto):
  _y = "This is Y"

class C(object):
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return "So you want "+name

class D(B,C):
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  a = A(None)
  b = B(a)
  print b.x
  print b.getY()
  d = D(a)
  print d.x
  print d.getY()
  print d.z
```